# Вырезать нужный кусок строки на Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Дана строка:

```
a = 'KJnkfnkgndkfgdrujt gegergnkr. AAAAAA: BB. sfjdkfgdgdnf. dfojvodfboWWEJNM.'
```

Как можно вырезать кусок строки, который идет после 'AAAAAA: ' и до '.', то есть нужно забрать 'BB'

Пробовал вот так:

```
a = a.split('AAAAAA: ')
d = re.match(r'\w.', a)
```

Ошибка, но наверняка есть более простой способ получить нужный результат в одну строку

Comment: можно регулярными выражениями. а вы как пытались?

Comment: дополнил ответ, как пробовал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну если там эти штуки точно есть, то:

```
a = 'KJnkfnkgndkfgdrujt gegergnkr. AAAAAA: BB. sfjdkfgdgdnf. dfojvodfboWWEJNM.'
print(a.split('AAAAAA: ')[1].split('.')[0])
# BB
```

А вообще лучше регулярками, конечно.

А ошибка у вас получается потому, что после `split` получается список, нужно было из него взять нужный элемент, а потом уже можно дальше что-то делать.

P.S. Если двоеточие встречается в строке только в этом месте, то можно проще (но с обрезанием лишних пробелов):

```
print(a.split(':')[1].split('.')[0].strip())
```

Comment: Нет, двоеточие встречается не один раз, первый вариант помог, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

a = 'KJnkfnkgndkfgdrujt gegergnkr. AAAAAA: BB. sfjdkfgdgdnf. dfojvodfboWWEJNM.'
res = re.search(r":\s(\w+)\.", a).group(1)
print(res) # BB
```